# Select columns to be displayed but retaining the original order

Tags: javascript

When the user chooses the columns to be shown, I would like to follow the order of the original array, for example:

Lets say I have this array of columns from a table:

```js
headers = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth']
```

I have a function that let my users choose which columns should be displayed

```js
table.selectedHeaders.map((column) => {
  return headers.find(header => header.value === column)
})
```

User selected in order: first, third, and second header... the filter will return this array:

```js
['first', 'third', 'second ']
```

I want it to be like this:

```js
['first', 'second', 'third']
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w8us9qdb/22

Comment: Please include a [mre].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: i have added a example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  const headers = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth'];
  const selectedHeaders = ['first', 'third', 'second'];
  const properOrderedHeaders = headers
   .filter(header => selectedHeaders.includes(header))
   .concat(selectedHeaders.filter(header => !headers.includes(header)));
```

it filters the array to contain only the headers while retaining their original orders. Then, any headers from selectedHeaders that were not found in the original headers array are appended to it.

Comment: Awesome, this worked perfectly, thank you alot

Answer (score 0):

checking for the values in the "selectedHeaders" array and then filtering the "headers" array to only include values that match. This way, the resulting array will have the same order as the "headers" array, but only include items that were selected by the user.

```js
const headers = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth']
const selectedHeaders = ['first', 'third', 'second'];

let col = headers.filter(item => selectedHeaders.includes(item));

console.log(col);
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to solve that is just using `.filter` with `selectedUser.includes` as conditional logic like this:

```js
let headers = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth']
let selectedUser = ['first', 'third','second']
let output = headers.filter(h => selectedUser.includes(h));
console.log(output)
```

```css
.as-console-row-code {
  white-space: initial !important;
}
```